# ROS and Gazebo trouble with an ODElink exception

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm new to ROS and Gazebo.

I was trying to convert a urdf model across for use in Gazebo. I've realised I need to convert the format into an SDF file version 1.0. (as I want to use a plugin publisher and subscriber to speak to ROS).

I've included this model in a .world file and am launching it from a .launch file based off a tutorial for ros_plugin .launch file
but I'm getting the following exception:

Msg Waiting for master

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ xxx

[ INFO] [1353386461.847382002]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...

Msg Waiting for master

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ hxxx

**Exception [ODELink.cc:317] Setting custom link base_linkmass to zero!**

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'gazebo::common::Exception' ..and so on
Abo

My base_link does have mass should it not? I've commented it out but it doesn't make much difference

Any Help would be appreciated

cheers
Peter

note I had to comment out some of the addresses to the host as the forum wouldn't let me post

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48619/ros-and-gazebo-trouble-with-an-odelink-exception./) by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1493 on 2012-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look I should close this. For some reason the model file wasn't parsing correctly, but wasn't throwing any errors. After closing down all my terminals and starting from a clean screen, my launch code started showing the parse errors, which I've been cleaning up.
Unfortunately I don't know the fundamental reason why this was not working correctly other than the model file was not correctly formatted for SDF 1.0.

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2012-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0